# Is there a way to replicate Postgres databases in Amazon RDS between regions?

Tags: postgresql, replication, amazon-rds

We have a Postgres RDS instance in the AWS Oregon Region.  For some supposed legal reasons, we have to host our client's European data in the Ireland AWS Region, but we need that data synchronized to the Oregon Region.  We will probably have to have an instance in the Singapore Region eventually, too.

We would like the databases to all be synchronized across regions.

Is this something that can even be done with Postgres RDS instances, or is MySQL the only database in RDS that supports this concept of replication between regions?

Any input on this matter would help.  We really enjoy how RDS makes administering the databases so easy, but if RDS can't allow us to sync databases between regions with Postgres, then we'll have to switch back to EC2 Linux instances with Postgres.

Comment: The last I saw RDS PostgreSQL can't do this, though of course the underlying PostgreSQL engine can. See this post: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/61305/get-wal-files-from-aws-rds-postgresql-instance

Answer (score 2):

AWS offers cross region data replication for MySQL RDS with a few clicks on aws console [cross-region replication for MySQL](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/cross-region-read-replicas-for-amazon-rds-for-mysql/), but not for postgreSQL yet, maybe in the future they will provide such functionality.

However, you might be able to implement such replication across regions with ec2 instances and avoiding RDS instances.